# 404 error on IIS6 when using WCF RIA services and SL4

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, iis-6, asp.net-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am hosting a SL4 application using WCF RIA services on IIS6 and I am using windows authentication. Log is something like:

```
/.../ClientBin/NameOfWebApp-AuthenticationDomainService.svc/binary/GetUser ... 404 0 2
```

Having previously set up this application on another 2003 server succesfully, I had the experience to configure .NET Framework 4. I mean I used "aspnet_regiis", "servicemodelreg", "httpcfg", etc. I have even created a new web site afterwards to make sure everything is in place. In fact, when I try to access my actual domain service using web browser, everything is working. So I believe WCF is correctly set up. I checked:

- web service extensions for .net framework v4 is allowed
- .svc extension is configured to v4 aspnet_isapi.dll
- anonymous access is disabled, only integrated windows authentication is enabled as at most one authentication scheme is allowed.

I can't see the reason why it is working on one server and not working on another. The fact is, I am going to make this installation on another critical production server and I have to make sure there are no surprises.

Do you have any ideas?

**Additional info:**

I guess since WCF is working in general, there is a problem with domain service host which handles service calls without svc files. I have the following settings already in my web.config:

```
   <system.web>
     <httpModules>
       <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
     </httpModules>
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
       <add name="DomainServiceModule"
             preCondition="managedHandler"
             type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, 
             System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, 
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
     </modules>
   </system.webServer>
```

Has anyone solved this issue with IIS6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am destined to answer my own questions. Having .svc extension set to use aspnet_isapi.dll is not enough, ***Verify that file exists*** setting should not be checked. That is what DomainServiceModule is for.